# How to compare lines with the same unique substring in one field and keep only those lines with the largest number in the last field?

Tags: awk

I have a file formatted with a series of segments of unique identifiers (`>lcl|ORF#_URS[:alnum:]:##:## foo, bar:##`) followed by a corresponding alpha string (`ALPHAALPHAALPHA:::0`) on the line directly below it. **Sample of file:**

```
>lcl|ORF1_URS0000000001:102:197 unnamed protein product:95
MVVGDNARKRTLIPHTSYGRKQGTFGPCAIR:::0
>lcl|ORF2_URS0000000001:1:93 unnamed protein product, partial:92
LNAGGRPNTCKSSGREKLASLESGGRVSNA:::0
>lcl|ORF3_URS0000000001:8:82 unnamed protein product:74
MAAGLTHASRAVERSLLLLRAADG:::0
>lcl|ORF4_URS0000000001:86:118 unnamed protein product:32
MPRNLPGSGG:::0
>lcl|ORF5_URS0000000001:193:152 unnamed protein product:41
MIAQGPKVPCFLP:::0
>lcl|ORF6_URS0000000001:167:135 unnamed protein product:32
MLSPVGRMRY:::0
>lcl|ORF7_URS0000000001:32:0 unnamed protein product, partial:32
MHVLGLPPAFN:::0
>lcl|ORF1_URS00000000M3:42:77 unnamed protein product:35
MINALCSYLLA:::0
>lcl|ORF2_URS00000000M3:174:236 unnamed protein product:62
MRGRSPTLVLRHGPDFYGRQ:::0
>lcl|ORF3_URS00000000M3:246:311 unnamed protein product:65
MDNGGNSDPAMPREGRRPYGL:::0
```

The key elements to focus on to solve this problem are the alphanumeric **URS identifiers** and the final field (**$4**) of lines beginning with **">"** and separated by **":"**.

I would like to keep only the lines for each *unique* alphanumeric URS identifier (e.g., `URS0000000001`, `URS00000000M3`, etc.) with the *largest value* in the final field of the same line (always begins with "`>`" and separated by "`:`"). If there are two or more lines with equal values in the final field for the same identifier, take the first or last (doesn't matter). **Example of desired output:**

```
>lcl|ORF1_URS0000000001:102:197 unnamed protein product:95
>lcl|ORF3_URS00000000M3:246:311 unnamed protein product:65
```

**OR** if its simpler:

```
URS0000000001    95
URS00000000M3    65
```

---

This is far beyond my abilities with `awk`, but I feel like my logic is halfway there. I tried to write an `awk` command that would search each line beginning with "`>`" and print the line when `$4` is greater than `$4` on another line with the same URS identifier:

```
awk -F":" 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} /^ *>/ {if (substr($1,11)==substr($1,11)){$4>$4}} 1' file
```

There must be a better method to match *substrings* of fields (`$1`) on different lines for subsequent comparison of linked/associated fields (`$4`) with `awk`. Ideas?

Comment: So basically, for every URS you want it and the biggest number at the end of that line?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Bingo. You've got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk -F ":" '
    NR==FNR {                                   # 1st loop to find the maximum valued line for each id
        if (match($1, "URS[[:alnum:]]+")) {     # check if $1 matches the format
            id = substr($1, RSTART, RLENGTH)    # extract the id
            if ($4 > a[id]) {                   # if $4 > max
                a[id] = $4                      # update the max value
                b[id] = $1                      # memorize the corresponding $1
            }
        }
        next
    }
    {                                           # 2nd loop to print the maximum valued line for each id
        if (match($1, "URS[[:alnum:]]+")) {
            id = substr($1, RSTART, RLENGTH)
            if ($1 == b[id]) print
        }
    }
' file file
```

Output:

```
>lcl|ORF1_URS0000000001:102:197 unnamed protein product:95
>lcl|ORF3_URS00000000M3:246:311 unnamed protein product:65
```

If the simpler output is good enough and you do not mind the order of appearance, a simpler alternative:

```
awk -F ":" '
    NR==FNR {
        if (match($1, "URS[[:alnum:]]+")) {
            id = substr($1, RSTART, RLENGTH)
            if ($4 > a[id]) a[id] = $4
        }
        next
    }
    END {
        for (i in a) print i, a[i]
    }
' file
```

Output:

```
URS00000000M3 65
URS0000000001 95
```

Comment: Thanks for attempting this gnarly problem. Unfortunately, both scripts give me an empty output file. Do you know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I cannot figure out what is the problem but I've heard some platform does not accept the regex character class such as `[[:alnum:]]`. Would you replace the second argument `"URS[[:alnum:]]+"` in the `match()` function with `"URS[0-9A-Za-z]+"` just as a try.

Comment: Thank you so much! **Your suggestion worked for the second script.** Oddly it didn't seem to work with the first script, but as long as one of them works for me, I'm happy. Thanks again.